# Randomise an array of 3 arrays of ids

Tags: jquery, random

I'm trying to randomise a set of 3 arrays within an array and then set links with ids that are selected from the randomisation, difficult to explain but hope my code helps you understand what I'm trying to do:

```
var options = { 
    option1: ["#boss", "#esprit", "#escada"],
    option2: [ "#esprit","#boss", "#escada"],
     option3: ["#escada",  "#esprit", "#boss" ]
};

var randomOption = options[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3 )];

    $("a.test1").attr("id", randomOption[0])
    $("a.test2").attr("id", randomOption[1])
    $("a.test3").attr("id", randomOption[2])
```

This code doesn't work, any ideas what I need to do?

Thanks.

Comment: `options` is an object so you cannot index the fields using an integer. This should be a 2D array.

Comment: right so how I do that?

Comment: its an object so could be accessed like this `options['option'+Math.floor(Math.random() * 3 )];` although, i see the different options are the same array of id's but in a different order, why not just have a single dimension array and shuffle it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to index by a random number, then you should make a 2-dimensional array.

```
var options = [
    ["#boss", "#esprit", "#escada"],
    ["#esprit", "#boss", "#escada"],
    ["#escada", "#esprit", "#boss"]
];

var randomOption = options[Math.floor(Math.random() * options.length)];

for (var i = 1; i <= options.length; i++)
    $("a.test" + i).attr("id", randomOption[i-1]);

for (var i = 1; i <= options.length; i++)
    console.log("Test " +i+ ": " + $("a.test" + i).attr("id"));
```

This is the JSFiddle for the code above: http://jsfiddle.net/XugvM/2

You could also make a 1-dimensional array and shuffle like @RoryPickering mentioned: http://jsfiddle.net/XugvM/8/

```
// Define a shuffle function for the Array class.
if (!Array.prototype.hasOwnProperty('shuffle')) {
    Array.prototype.shuffle = function(array) {
        var counter = this.length, temp, index;

        // While there are elements in the array.
        while (counter > 0) {
            // Pick a random index.
            index = Math.floor(Math.random() * counter);

            // Decrease counter by 1.
            counter--;

            // Swap the last element with it.
            temp = this[counter];
            this[counter] = this[index];
            this[index] = temp;
        }
    }
}

// Define variables.
var options = ["#boss", "#esprit", "#escada"];
var optionsLength = options.length;

// Shuffle options.
options.shuffle();

// Assign the ids for the anchors.
for (var i = 0; i < optionsLength; i++)
    $("a.test" + (i + 1)).attr("id", options[i]);

// Print each of the ids in the log console.
for (var i = 1; i <= optionsLength; i++)
    console.log("Test " +i+ ": " + $("a.test" + i).attr("id"));
```

Answer (score 0):

have a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/M6z6M/

**code**

```
var options = {
    option1: ["#boss", "#esprit", "#escada"],
    option2: ["#esprit", "#boss", "#escada"],
    option3: ["#escada", "#esprit", "#boss"]
};
var rnd = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1);
var randomOption = options["option" + rnd];

$("a.test1").attr("id", randomOption[0])
$("a.test2").attr("id", randomOption[1])
$("a.test3").attr("id", randomOption[2])
```

click on each link to see printed the id of that link